# Dafny generic type array error

Tags: dafny

In trying to verify a generic FIFO queue backed by an array I ran into a confusing error. The queue was found in [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/krml233.pdf) paper, authored by the creator of Dafny.

The error in question is:

> unless an initializer is provided for the array elements, a new array of 'Data' must have empty size

which relates to both lines allocating an array via `new Data[whatever]` in the constructor and the enqueue method.

Dafny version: Dafny 2.0.0.00922 technical preview 0

Full code for reference.

```
class {:autocontracts} SimpleQueue<Data>
{
    ghost var Contents: seq<Data>;
    var a: array<Data>;
    var m: int, n: int;
    predicate Valid() {
        a != null && a.Length != 0 && 0 <= m <= n <= a.Length && Contents == a[m..n]
    }
    constructor ()
    ensures Contents == [];
    {
        a := new Data[10];
        m := 0;
        n := 0;
        Contents := [];
    }
    method Enqueue(d: Data)
    ensures Contents == old(Contents) + [d];
    {
        if n == a.Length {
            var b := a;
            if m == 0 {
                b := new Data[2 * a.Length];
            }
            forall (i | 0 <= i < n - m) {
                b[i] := a[m + i];
            }
            a, m, n := b, 0, n - m;
        }
        a[n], n, Contents := d, n + 1, Contents + [d];
    }

    method Dequeue() returns (d: Data)
    requires Contents != [];
    ensures d == old(Contents)[0] && Contents == old(Contents)[1..];
    {
        assert a[m] == a[m..n][0];
        d, m, Contents := a[m], m + 1, Contents[1..];
    }
}
method Main()
{
    var q := new SimpleQueue();
    q.Enqueue(5); q.Enqueue(12);
    var x := q.Dequeue();
    assert x == 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time of writing that paper, Dafny's type system has been generalized to support types that are not "default initializable". This has led to some backwards incompatibilities.

The easiest fix is to change

```
class SimpleQueue<Data>
```

to

```
class SimpleQueue<Data(0)>
```

which means that the type variable `Data` can only be instantiated with default-initializable types.

Another fix is to change the constructor to accept a default value for type `Data` as an argument. Then you can allocate an array using an initializer function, as in

```
new Data[10] (_ => d)
```